# How do you completely disable the space-switching animations in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, animation

Is there a way to completely disable the animations when switching from one space to another in Yosemite? Everything I have found so far is for previous versions of OS X.

I have tried all of these without success:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-swoosh-animation-off -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -int 0; killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock space-animation-duration -int 0; killall Dock
```

I want to avoid installing a tool like TotalSpace if possible.

Comment: are you trying to disable spaces altogether or just the animation when switching spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You *can* change the speed of switching into Mission Control. To do that in terminal Run:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -int 0; killall Dock
```

To switch back to defaults run:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration; killall Dock
```