# How can I switch among apps with Cmd/whatever + number keys, as on Unix desktop environments?

Tags: window-manager, multitasking

How can I switch among application windows using [Cmd/Opt + 1/2/3...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813262/which-desktop-environments-allow-switching-among-windows-with-supernumbers) etc, like on Unity or KDE?

Why? This is especially handy if you often switch among the same few apps, e.g. a browser, a file manager and an IDE, but also have other apps open, so Alt+Tabbing to the desired window would take more time.

That keyboard shortcut saves me probably 5 seconds per minute on the average, so ~40 minutes a day, and it's supported by Windows as well.

I tried using the native Automator and Keyboard shortcuts in System settings, but the shortcut is only picked up in *some* applications (e.g. Automator, Webstorm), but most applications seem to consume it before it reaches the system.

## To create the shortcut with Automator:

1. <kbd>⌘+Space</kbd> and launch <kbd>Automator</kbd>
2. Choose "Quick action"
3. Set the "Workflow receives current" to no "input"
4. In the panel on the left, filter for the <kbd>Run Shell Script</kbd> Action and double click it
5. In the `Run shell script` text area, replace `cat` with the command to run your application, e.g. `open -a "Google Chrome"`.
6. <kbd>File -> Save</kbd> and name your shortcut, e.g. `Chrome launch/switch to`

### Assign the keyboard shortcut

1. <kbd>⌘+Space</kbd> and type `keyboard shortcuts` to access it in System Settings
2. Click <kbd>Services -> General</kbd> and you'll see your newly created shortcut
3. Double click `none` and press your hotkey combo, e.g. <kbd>⌘+1</kbd>
4. Click <kbd>Done</kbd>

I'm looking for a more reliable solution than the system's Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You can switch Spaces with Ctrl/Number. If you put one app on each Space, you've got it. [Doesn't work for fullscreened apps].

Comment: @Tetsujin: I don't want the whole animation of switching spaces. I want to quickly switch for example between my IDE and the browser when I look up some reference information.

Comment: There's no native way to do what you want.

Comment: In contrast with the open-source Linux world, it feels frustrating and powerless to be unable to provide feedback to Apple about this.

Comment: @DanDascalescu The type of feedback you can give via the links at the bottom of https://www.apple.com/contact/ ?

Comment: @nohillside: I was looking for an issue tracker, like [Google's](issuetracker.google.com/), or Ubuntu's, or KDE's etc. Apple doesn't have a public one. The closest to that concept seems to be a community forum, https://discussions.apple.com/community/macos (which isn't linked on that contact page).

Comment: discussions.apple.com is a support site. Apple doesn‘t have a public issue tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karabiner-Elements can be used to run an `open` shell command. It'll open it if the application is closed, and focus if it's already open. If you create `cmd-numbers.json` in `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/`, you'll see new rules in Karabiner under <kbd>Complex modifications | Add rule</kbd>:

```json
{
  "title": "Launch apps with Cmd+<number>",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Finder",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "1",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": "command"
            }
          },
          "to": {
            "repeat": false,
            "shell_command": "open -b com.apple.finder"
          },
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Firefox",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "2",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": "command"
            }
          },
          "to": {
            "repeat": false,
            "shell_command": "open -a Firefox"
          },
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `-b` flag means bundle ID. You can also use `open -a Finder.app`.